# Auto-relacionamento em tabela de Grupo com Laravel e Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma tabela de `grupo` com os campos:

> id (**int not null auto-increment**)
>
> description (**varchar**)
>
> grupoid (**int null**)

***Como seria:***

- 1) a `migration` correspondente a essa tabela?
- 2) a criação do `model Eloquent` com o relacionamento?
- 3) como poderia saber se um determinado `id é Pai`, alguma técnica?
- 4) se o `id é Pai` como carregar os `filhos nos relacionamentos`?

Comment: Queria entender o voto negativo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>**Auto Relacionamento Laravel**</sup>

> 1) a migration correspondente a essa tabela?

Para criar o arquivo (*o modelo em branco*) no `console` faça:

```
php artisan make:migration Grupo
```

**Configurando:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Grupo extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grupo', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {    
            $table->increments('id');    
            $table->string('description', 50);    
            $table->integer("grupoid", false, true)
                ->nullable();    
            $table->index("grupoid");    
            $table->foreign("grupoid")
                ->references('id')
                ->on('grupo');                
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('grupo');
    }
}
```

**Gerar Tabela:**

```
php artisan migrate
```

---

> 2) a criação do model Eloquent com o relacionamento?

Para criar o arquivo (*o modelo em branco*) no `console` faça:

```
php artisan make:model Grupo
```

**Configurando:**

```
namespace App\Models;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grupo extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = array('description','grupoid');
    protected $table = "grupo";
    public $timestamps = false;

    //relacionamento (auto-relacionamento) item 4 
    public function grupos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Grupo::class, 'grupoid', 'id');
    }

    // um técnica do item 3
    public function isFather()
    {
        return is_null($this->attributes['grupoid']);
    }

    // aqui seria o item 3  
    protected $appends = ['is_father'];
    public function getIsFatherAttribute()
    {
        return is_null($this->attributes['grupoid']);
    }
}
```

---

> 3) como poderia saber se um determinado id é Pai, alguma técnica?

No item ***2)*** foi criado duas técnicas:

- Uma seria criar um método e comparar se o `grupoid` é `null` `(is_null)` e foi criado o método `isFather()`:

---

```
public function isFather()
{
    return is_null($this->attributes['grupoid']);
}
```

- Mas, somente com método ele não sai nos resultados de `Array` ou `Json`, então criaremos um `appends` nesse `Model Grupo`:

---

```
protected $appends = ['is_father'];
public function getIsFatherAttribute()
{
    return is_null($this->attributes['grupoid']);
}
```

tendo como resultado no formato `JSON`:

```
{"id":4,"description":"Grupo 2","grupoid":null,"is_father":true,"grupos":[]}
```

---

> 4) se o id é Pai como carregar os filhos nos relacionamentos?

Simplesmente com o comando [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$grupo = App\Models\Grupo();
$grupo->with('grupos')->find(4);
```