# Obter descrição de sub-categoria PHP Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Olá,

Preciso obter a descrição da minha categoria pai, porém não consigo obter a descrição no mesmo select, somente consigo obter o id da categoria pai.

Tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo tem o código que estou obtendo meus produtos e a categoria que ele esta vinculado, também obtenho o código da categoria pai, ***porém como vou obter a descrição da categoria pai?***

```
public static function getMovimentos() {
    return DB::table('movimentos')
                    ->join('produtos', 'produtos.id', '=', 'movimentos.id_produto')
                    ->join('categorias', 'categorias.id', '=', 'produtos.categoria_id')
                    ->select('movimentos.id as id',
                            'categorias.nome as desc_sub',
                            'categorias.id_categoria as id_sub',
                            'produtos.categoria_id as categoria_id',
                            'produtos.id as idProduto',
                            'movimentos.tipo_movimento as tipo_movimento',
                            'movimentos.observacoes as observacoes',
                            'movimentos.quantidade as quantidade',
                            'movimentos.id_produto as id_produto',
                            'movimentos.serie as serie',
                            'movimentos.created_at as data_criacao',
                            'produtos.descricao as descricao',
                            'produtos.codigo_alternativo as codigo_alternativo')
                    ->where('movimentos.id_estoque', '=', session()->get('session_estoque_id'))
            ->get();
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Auto-relacionamento em tabela de Grupo com Laravel e Eloquent?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154688/auto-relacionamento-em-tabela-de-grupo-com-laravel-e-eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar um join para o auto relacionamento de categoria:

```
public static function getMovimentos() {
    return DB::table('movimentos')
                ->join('produtos', 'produtos.id', '=', 'movimentos.id_produto')
                ->join('categorias', 'categorias.id', '=', 'produtos.categoria_id')
                ->join('categoria_pai', 'categorias.id', '=', 'categoria_pai.id_categoria')
                ->select('movimentos.id as id',
                        'categorias.nome as desc_sub',
                        'categorias.id_categoria as id_sub',
                        'categoria_pai.nome as desc_pai
                        'produtos.categoria_id as categoria_id',
                        'produtos.id as idProduto',
                        'movimentos.tipo_movimento as tipo_movimento',
                        'movimentos.observacoes as observacoes',
                        'movimentos.quantidade as quantidade',
                        'movimentos.id_produto as id_produto',
                        'movimentos.serie as serie',
                        'movimentos.created_at as data_criacao',
                        'produtos.descricao as descricao',
                        'produtos.codigo_alternativo as codigo_alternativo')
                ->where('movimentos.id_estoque', '=', session()->get('session_estoque_id'))
        ->get();
}
```