# Montar Array com as categorias e subcategorias que estão na mesma tabela

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

estou tentado montar um array, mas não estou conseguindo, diante da seguinte tabela, preciso montar o array como no exemplo embaixo da foto.

projeto em laravel 6.x

[image: tabela com as categorias e subcategorias]

nas colunas 'categoria_id' que está 'null', são categorias principais.
E as 'categorias_id com id, são as subcategorias, com a id da categoria principal,
preciso de algo com neste exemplo que montei abaixo.

```
$categorias = Categorias::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

$categoria = $categorias->where('categoria_id', '=', null)->toArray();

$subcategoria = $categorias->where('categoria_id', '!=', null)->toArray();
```

até separei, mas não consigo juntar elas, como mostro no exemplo abaixo.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [categoria] => Lanches
            [categoria_id] => 
            [status] => 0
            [ordem] => 
            [subcats] => Array
               (
                     [3] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 5
                             [categoria] => Lanches Tradicionais
                             [categoria_id] => 1
                             [status] => 0
                             [ordem] => 
                         )

                     [4] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 6
                             [categoria] => Lanches Gourmet
                             [categoria_id] => 1
                             [status] => 0
                             [ordem] => 
                         )

                     [5] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 7
                             [categoria] => Lanches Caseiros
                             [categoria_id] => 1
                             [status] => 0
                             [ordem] => 
                         )

                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [categoria] => Porções
            [categoria_id] => 
            [status] => 0
            [ordem] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [categoria] => Sucos
            [categoria_id] => 
            [status] => 0
            [ordem] => 
        )

)
```

já tentei montar de várias formas, mas nenhum sucesso, não sei mais oque fazer.

Comment: você recebe essas informações da base de dados no formato bruto?

Comment: sim, em laravel.. retorno todos as categorias..

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, da uma olhada

Comment: Eu fiz a resposta e a opção 2 resolve melhor o seu problema, dá uma olhada!

Comment: top mano! tive que sair, cheguei agora vou testar, mas de cara já imagino que vai resolver, já te respondo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Conforme a primeiro exemplo:

Primeiro se precisa filtrar os dados que estão com `categoria_id === null`, exemplo:

```
$arrayCategoria = array_filter($array, function ($item) {
  return empty($item['categoria_id']);
});
```

e depois com as categorias já separadas precisa iterar sobre os itens que são as categorias e buscar no `array` principal as Sub Categorias com outro `array_filter`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayCategoria); $i++) {
  $id = $arrayCategoria[$i]['id'];
  $arrayCategoria[$i]['cats'] = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($item) use ($id) {
      return $item['categoria_id'] === $id;
    }
  );
}
```

---

Código completo:

```
<?php    
$array = [
  ['id' => 1, 'categoria' => 'Lanches', 
   'categoria_id' => null, 'status' => 0, 'ordem' => null],
  ['id' => 2, 'categoria' => 'Porções', 
   'categoria_id' => null, 'status' => 0, 'ordem' => null],
  ['id' => 4, 'categoria' => 'Sucos', 
   'categoria_id' => null, 'status' => 0, 'ordem' => null],
  ['id' => 5, 'categoria' => 'Lanches Tradicionais', 
   'categoria_id' => 1, 'status' => 0, 'ordem' => null],
  ['id' => 6, 'categoria' => 'Lanches Gourmet', 
   'categoria_id' => 1, 'status' => 0, 'ordem' => null],
  ['id' => 7, 'categoria' => 'Lanches Caseiros', 
   'categoria_id' => 1, 'status' => 0, 'ordem' => null],
];   

$arrayCategoria = array_filter($array, function ($item) {
  return empty($item['categoria_id']);
});    

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayCategoria); $i++) {
  $id = $arrayCategoria[$i]['id'];
  $arrayCategoria[$i]['cats'] = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($item) use ($id) {
      return $item['categoria_id'] === $id;
    }
  );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayCategoria);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

[Link Online](https://ideone.com/hUe6hQ)

---

2. Com Auto Relacionamento

A outra forma seria pra mim a ideal onde o próprio `Eloquent` resolveria com um [Auto Relacionamento pergunta que eu mesmo fiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154688/auto-relacionamento-em-tabela-de-grupo-com-laravel-e-eloquent) e a resposta.

No seu `Model` `Categorias` adicione um método:

```
//relacionamento (auto-relacionamento) item 4 
public function subCategorias()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Categorias::class, 'categoria_id', 'id');
}
```

e na hora de utilizar faça o seguinte código:

```
Categorias::with('subCategorias')->get();
```

---

**Nota:** *Utilize a segunda opção é mais fácil manter a evolução do código e o item 1. fica com fazer manualmente esse código*

Comment: Você é muito monstro cara! funcionou perfeitamente a 2º opção, mas a 1º também vai ajudar, pra fazer uma outra coisa, sensacional! muito obrigado mano!